# How to run ffmpeg with php in debian 10

Tags: php, ffmpeg, debian, debian-buster

i am trying to run a ffmpeg command with my php in Debian 10, but its not working, but the command is working perfectly in windows. The command is to add a watermark and a text at the bottom of the video.
Here is the php code

```
<?php
    $new_file="new.mp4";
    $text="eloke";
    $video_name="video.mp4";
    echo file_exists($new_file)? "<video autoplay src='$new_file'></video>":"No file";
   
    $cmd="ffmpeg -i $video_name -i watermark.jpg -filter_complex overlay=W-w-5:H-h-15[video];[video]drawtext=\"text=$text:fontcolor=white:fontsize=12:x=(w-text_w)-5: y=(h-text_h)-5\" $new_file";
    exec("$cmd 2>&1", $output);
    var_dump($output);
?>
```

I am getting this in the browser

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(103) "sh: 1: [video]drawtext=text=eloke:fontcolor=white:fontsize=12:x=(w-text_w)-5: y=(h-text_h)-5: not found" }
```

Please what am i doing wrong

Comment: I thing you need some more quotes around the argument of overlay. The ```;``` will end the ffmpeg command

Comment: @Thomas how can i do that

Comment: I have not tested it but I would try 
```$cmd="ffmpeg -i $video_name -i watermark.jpg -filter_complex 'overlay=W-w-5:H-h-15[video];[video]drawtext=\"text=$text:fontcolor=white:fontsize=12:x=(w-text_w)-5: y=(h-text_h)-5\"' $new_file";```

Comment: @Thomas i got this error `Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args '"text=eloke:fontcolor=white:fontsize=12:x=(w-text_w)-5: y=(h-text_h)-5"' [24] => Error initializing complex filters. [25] => Invalid argument )`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following snippet and replace into your original code:

```
$cmd = "ffmpeg -i ".$video_name." -i watermark.jpg -filter_complex overlay=W-w-5:H-h-15[video];[video]drawtext=\"text=".$text.":fontcolor=white:fontsize=12:x=(w-text_w)-5: y=(h-text_h)-5\" ".$new_file;
$cmd = escapeshellcmd($cmd);
exec($cmd." > /path/to/stdout_file 2>&1", $output);
```

Also, [beware of using escapeshellcmd()](https://gist.github.com/Zenexer/40d02da5e07f151adeaeeaa11af9ab36)